# Culture name is not supported

Tags: asp.net

I'm receiving "culture name 'uploads' is not supported" when my ASP.NET application start. Where do I have to view/debug to toggle the error?

A full-text search for "uploads" returns 0 entries in my project.

Answer (score 25):

I've deleted this folder and it solved the problem:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8dfb04ef\44bf70fb\uploads

Comment: search and deletion of 'uploads' folder under Temporary ASP.NET Files solved my problem as well. +1

Comment: +1.  Depending on your setup, the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder may instead be under %TEMP%.

Answer (score 14):

Do not worry, it is not a real error.

When the runtime tries to find which resource assemblies exists, it tries to enumerate folders where compiled DLL files reside. It assumes the name of the folder is the culture name, so it tries to create a culture for it. Unfortunately uploads is a folder which is created automatically by ASP.NET, and it is obviously not a culture :).

The runtime ignores some predefined folders like "hash", but not "uploads". So we have to live with it.

Comment: So what can he do about it?

Answer (score 5):

I am getting the exact same error.  ["culture name 'uploads' is not supported"].  I do not know what is causing it but I've been able to get around it by **clicking [Debug|Exceptions (Ctrl-alt-E) and un-checking "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".**  I do not have an 'uploads' folder or file in my project and there is nothing in my project that has anything to do with multilingual support and the error fires right off the bat when I run my project ... looking at the call stack just walks me through a whole lot of mscorlib calls.  I have no clue why it's even getting called.

Answer (score 5):

JumpingLethalRampage, instead of unchecking all "**Commong Language Runtime Exceptions**," you could uncheck just "**Common Language Runtime Exceptions > System > System.ArgumentException**." You don't need to uncheck all CLR items.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like maybe you have some code somewhere that is trying to set the culture based on a URL pattern (this may be tracked down if it is possible to get a stack trace). For example, sometimes I'll set up multi-lingual sites with [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) like this:

```
http://www.example.com/en-US/
http://www.example.com/es-MX/
```

I'll then have code in my base page that looks at the URL and attempts to set the culture based on the URL path. But if you tried to hit a URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/uploads
```

It would fail with an error like what you are seeing if you just blindly take the first path element and try to use it as the culture without checking it first.

Comment: no :-) if can step in the debugger but it says "no source code". maybe it's loading the app in the global.asax

Comment: Sounds like Global.asax would be the place to start then.  Probably in begin request?

Comment: This helped me understand why disabling CLR exceptions (or, rather, disabling Visual Studio from notifying me when [*all*] CLR exceptions are thrown) makes sense – there might be code that's throwing an exception, but innocuously. *I just wasn't noticing those exceptions previously* (because I just recently **enabled** VS to break when [any] CLR exception is thrown). I think I might try to hunt down whatever's throwing the exceptions – *eventually* – but not today.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is it built upon [DotNetNuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke) (and not a simple ASP.NET application), this kind of error generally occurs in DotNetNuke due to the issue described in *[Culture name '__page' is not supported](http://www.datasprings.com/Products/ProductForums/tabid/727/forumid/3/tpage/1/view/topic/postid/3271/language/en-US/Default.aspx#3276)*.

If you are not using DotNetNuke, check your Application_Start code (in the `Global.asax` file). It might be setting the CultureInfo. Or check your `web.config` file for any invalid culture values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your search through the project wasn't restrictive (widest possible search in all files), then my guess would be that your browser has a User language set to a custom string - "uploads".

In IE, you can check via Tools -> Options -> Languages -> Add -> User defined language.