# .NET 4.0 debug, cold start performance

Tags: .net, performance, debugging, exception, .net-4.0

This problem has been driving me crazy for the past week.

We have migrated our 3.5 Solution to 4.0 (started using EF4), no big issues here. i already been using Visual Studio 2010 Final for a while without any problem.

Migrated the solution, and associated third party assemblies to .net 4.0, and although run-time performance is in level with 3.5, launching the debugger **is now taking about 2:30 to 3:00**, on several good machines (Core i7, Core i5 Laptops and Phenom 4x Desktops with plenty of ram).

**On 3.5 solution this all process took about 20-30 seconds**!!, Lucky if we start the site without debugging and attach the debugger only afterwords there is no problem, and everything seems OK.

The output window i'm getting more than **4000 first time exceptions**, that seem to be slowing the process down:

*A first chance exception of type 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*

I have already debugged this exception and no conclusion, it seems that on CultureInfo method name = Resx, and obviously this is not a correct culture:

```
    public CultureInfo(String name, bool useUserOverride) { 
    if (name==null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name",
            Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_String"));
    } 
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    // Get our data providing record 
    this.m_cultureData = CultureData.GetCultureData(name, useUserOverride);

    if (this.m_cultureData == null)
        throw new CultureNotFoundException(
            "name", name, Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_CultureNotSupported"));

    this.m_name = this.m_cultureData.CultureName;
    this.m_isInherited = (this.GetType() != typeof(System.Globalization.CultureInfo)); 
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CultureInfo(string name, bool useUserOverride) Line 264 + 0xef bytes  C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpServerUtility.CreateReadOnlyCultureInfo(string name) + 0xb8 bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Util.IsCultureName(string s) + 0x84 bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Util.GetCultureName(string virtualPath) + 0x4a bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.HashCodeCombiner.AddResourcesDirectory(string directoryName) + 0x18c bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.HashCodeCombiner.AddResourcesDirectory(string directoryName) + 0x16c bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.HashCodeCombiner.AddResourcesDirectory(string directoryName) + 0x16c bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate2(System.Web.Compilation.StandardDiskBuildResultCache diskCache) + 0x13a bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(System.Web.Compilation.StandardDiskBuildResultCache diskCache) + 0x38 bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.RegularAppRuntimeModeInitialize() + 0xaf bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Initialize() + 0x106 bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InitializeBuildManager() + 0xb8 bytes    
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, System.Security.Policy.PolicyLevel policyLevel, System.Exception appDomainCreationException) + 0x15f bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.InitializeHostingFeatures(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, System.Security.Policy.PolicyLevel policyLevel, System.Exception appDomainCreationException) + 0x3c bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager appManager, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, System.Security.Policy.PolicyLevel policyLevel, System.Exception appDomainCreationException) + 0x224 bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager appManager, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, System.Security.Policy.PolicyLevel policyLevel) + 0x1d bytes 
[Appdomain Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0xfd1 bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0x2f bytes    
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.GetAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0x67 bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObjectInternal(string appId, System.Type type, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, bool failIfExists, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0x4d bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObject(string appId, System.Type type, string virtualPath, string physicalPath, bool failIfExists, bool throwOnError) + 0x8d bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObject(string appId, System.Type type, string virtualPath, string physicalPath, bool failIfExists) + 0x35 bytes  
WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server.GetHost() + 0x14b bytes  
WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server.OnSocketAccept(object acceptedSocket) + 0xa7 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state) Line 1507 + 0xb bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) Line 441 + 0xe bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() Line 1486 + 0x22 bytes   C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() Line 974   C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() Line 1341 + 0x5 bytes   C#
```

- Have anybody had the same problem?
- Any ideas how to find the root cause
  of this exception (stack trace is not
  conclusive) or/and the performance
  degradation?

Comment: You already know why it is so slow.  You haven't posted anything that would help us help you, seeing the stack trace is *essential*.

Comment: Just updated the question with the stack trace, hope it helps

Comment: Does this help at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116821/net-4-0-culturenotfoundexception