# Setting CurrentCulture in VSTO Addin

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto, culture, regional-settings

I am creating a VSTO addin for Excel 2007. All works fine on my development computer with English(UK) regional settings. However some end users will have other settings.

All works fine when adding information to the database, however when I try and fill a datatable with English(US) regional settings it fails.

```
Dim TA As New DB_InquiriesTableAdapters.qry_InquiriesTableAdapter
Dim DB As New DB_Inquiries.qry_InquiriesDataTable
TA.Fill(DB) 'FAILS HERE as date format is incorrect for regional settings
```

I have tried setting Thread.CurrentCulture in the addin startup but this throws and exception saying:

MSCORLIB Culture not supported

Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116821/net-4-0-culturenotfoundexception

Comment: Just read through, tried deleting files as it said, but still not working.

Comment: You are under the conditions mentioned there? The chosen solution says that it was bug of the VS 2010 Beta.

Comment: No Using 2013 Pro. I found a solution anyway! Posting now.

Comment: Perfect! Write it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

My original code was something like this:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class MyClass

Public Sub MySub
    Thread.CurrentCulture=New CultureInfo("en-GB")
    Thread.CurrentUICulture=New CultureInfo("en-GB")
    ....
End Sub

End Class
```

It would throw an exception when trying to set the current culture.

New code:

```
Public Class MyClass

Public Sub MySub
    My.Application.SetCulture("en-GB")
    ....
End Sub

End Class
```

The application is a VSTO Excel Addin written in VS2013 Professional and the class is linked to a WPF UserControl hosted in a Winforms Form.

Hope this helps explain the answer a little better.

Comment: I guess that My.Application.SetCulture is a new method in 2013 (cannot test). It is not present in any previous VS version neither is possible to find any MSDN documentation about it.