# Web Service Error: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException culture name 'en-il' is not supported

Tags: .net, vb.net, soap

While this is similar to [How to solve this Exception "Culture is not Supported"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554944/how-to-solve-this-exception-culture-is-not-supported) I thought I'd post this as its specific to accessing a Web Service from a .NET application.  I recently ported my very old project to a new machine with windows 11.  The application has a call to a soap web service and I received this error:

```
 System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> 
 System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2001). ---> 
System.ArgumentException: Culture name 'en-il' is not supported.
Parameter name: name  .....
```

It was working fine on the old machine.
The data service is sent a dataset (xml document) from the client to the server and then processes it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identity that the dataset in the client request has a property called Locale whose value is by default set to the default input language of the client.  In my case the new machine's default input language was 'en-il'.
The solution is either to set the locale of the dataset to en-il prior to the soap request,

```
mydataset.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
```

or changing the default input language of the local machine.