# Visual Studio strange startup exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

For some reason VS was not breaking on exception when running in debug mode, so I followed the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116896/visual-studio-how-to-break-on-handled-exceptions) to go to Debug -> Exceptions and enable the CLR exceptions. I now get this error:

```
System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException occurred
  Message=Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
uploads is an invalid culture identifier.
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=name
  InvalidCultureName=uploads
  StackTrace:
       at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
  InnerException:
```

This error occurs on startup, but only some of the time.

The advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116821/net-4-0-culturenotfoundexception) then recommends that I do the exact opposite and uncheck the debug the CLR option, but I am then back to square one! A poster suggests that it is a bug, but the post is two years old, so surely that has been fixed by now.

I am not using globalisation.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868880/culture-name-is-not-supported