# is it necessary to handle exceptions shown in the IntelliTrace

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, exception, intellitrace

today when checking a breakpoint in visual studio 2010 , I saw that several exceptions had been thrown during execution of application .

[image]

[image]

but none of them are related to my code and the application works as it should. is there any way to handle these and is it necessary to handle these exceptions or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to worry much about these as you have already figured it out that I don’t effect your program directly.

These warning/exceptions are mostly related run-time, default directory structures etc and the way they are defined we can’t do much about them.

Let’s say for the exception `Culture not supported` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868880/culture-name-is-not-supported) for explanation of why it happens

Moreover if you use some third party plugin like `Resharper` etc. you’ll get a lot of Code errors and suggestions and some related to assemblies this may bother your for some time that your code has so many glitches but again you don’t have much control over them and leaving them as it is doesn’t affect the main program anyhow.